# C++ sequence generator with init value by function enclosure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++14, enclose

I have a question: Is below piece of code valid and whether it is optimum for sequence generator function in C++14?

```
auto sequenceGen = [](int&& init) {
    int counter = init;
    return [counter=std::move(counter)]() mutable { return ++counter; };
};
auto getSeq1 = sequenceGen(100);
cout << getSeq1()<< endl;
cout << getSeq1()<< endl;
```

If not how should it be implemented?

Comment: "piece of code".

Comment: It's strange, at least. Why would you pass an int by rvalue reference? Reference size is the same as the pointer size, int is either same or smaller, and why moving it (same considerations).

Comment: `auto const sequenceGen = [](int init){ return [init]()mutable{ return ++init; } };` should do (but not thread safe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive types like `int` do not benefit from *move semantics*, as moves are exactly the same as copies. Your code can be simplified to:

```
auto sequenceGen = [](int init) {
    return [init]() mutable { return ++init; };
};

auto getSeq1 = sequenceGen(100);
cout << getSeq1() << '\n';
cout << getSeq1() << '\n';
```

Also avoid using `std::endl` unless you want to force the buffer to be flushed as it's inefficient compared to `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks @vittorio-romeo , for int move semantics is not necessary, but it was only a simplification. I will be using this as template function.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted (and consider upvoting) if you're satisfied with it @JarodSmith